# Why is this join query not working with createQueryBuilder?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, silex

This works fine

```
SELECT * FROM podcasttags
INNER JOIN podcast
ON podcasttags.podcastid = podcast.id
INNER JOIN tag
ON podcasttags.tagid = tag.id
```

but when I try to use doctrine1 createQueryBuilder I get an error:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->db->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('pt')
                ->from('podcasttags', 'pt')
                ->innerJoin('podcast p ON pt.podcastid = p.id')
                ->innerJoin('tag t ON pt.tagid = t.id');
$statement = $queryBuilder->execute();
$podcastData = $statement->fetchAll();
```

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder::innerJoin(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\src\FDRPodcast\Repository\PodcastRepository.php
>   on line 49 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder.php
>   on line 601
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder::innerJoin(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\src\FDRPodcast\Repository\PodcastRepository.php
>   on line 49 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder.php
>   on line 601
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: join in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder.php
>   on line 606
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: alias in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder.php
>   on line 607
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder::innerJoin(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\src\FDRPodcast\Repository\PodcastRepository.php
>   on line 50 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder.php
>   on line 601
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder::innerJoin(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\src\FDRPodcast\Repository\PodcastRepository.php
>   on line 50 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FDRPodcast\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder.php
>   on line 601

Comment: Refer to [doctrine manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) doctrine works with entities not directly with tables and off-course innerjoin() call is wrong

Answer (score 1):

An example from the Doctrine manual:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.id')
    ->from('User u')
    ->leftJoin('u.Groups g')
    ->innerJoin('u.Phonenumbers p')
    ->leftJoin('u.Email e');
```

So your query should look something like this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->db->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('pt')
            ->from('podcasttags pt')
            ->innerJoin('pt.podcast p')
            ->innerJoin('pt.tag t');
```

It goes on to say that something like "pt.tagid = t.id" is unnecessary because Doctrine associates primary keys by default. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your first code block is for doctrine 1, the second is for doctrine 2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are missing some arguments from innerJoin method of QueryBuilder.

You call the method in a wrong manner

```
->innerJoin('podcast p ON pt.podcastid = p.id')
```

The method innerJoin needs four arguments

1. Alias of the from table
2. The join table
3. Alias of the join table
4. Join condition

The working query

```
SELECT * FROM podcasttags
INNER JOIN podcast
ON podcasttags.podcastid = podcast.id
INNER JOIN tag
ON podcasttags.tagid = tag.id
```

With Doctrine DBAL would be

```
$queryBuilder = $this->db->createQueryBuilder()
         ->select('*')
         ->from('podcasttags', 'pt')
         ->innerJoin('pt', 'podcast', 'p', 'pt.podcastid = p.id')
         ->innerJoin('pt', 'tag', 't', 'pt.tagid = t.id');
```

Finally is worth note that if you call the method of QueryBuilder->getSQL() it output the current query formed with QueryBuilder object.